# Error after compiling .IDL file for Firefox accessibility

Tags: c++, firefox, mfc, accessibility, idl

I've encountered a very annoying problem while working with [Firefox MSAA](http://www.mozilla.org/access/windows/at-apis) (). I tried to compile IDL file from cmd but it failed. Then I added it to the project and ran build. After VS compiled interface file there were two C files - ISimpleDOMDocument_h.h and ISimpleDOMDocument_i.c I added those to the project. But now I cant build because of such error

**error C1853: 'Debug\TestProj.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)    d:\projects\testproj\testproj\isimpledomdocument_i.c**

Any clues?

Comment: Which IDL compiler did you use?  The one provided from Mozilla Utilities, or the one from MSVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C

Which is your problem.  Not sure how you got in this pickle, the mumble_i.c file is generated by MIDL and should *not* contain an #include "stdafx.h" directive.  Don't edit the file.  Right-click it in Solution Explorer window, Properties, C/C++, Precompiled Headers, Create/Use = "Not using Precompiled Headers".